# Bulkcopy the updated & newly inserted data between differenet databases using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

This is my first post.. I have 2 SQL Server databases located on different servers..

Let's say SDT for source data table from source database SDB to DDT (Destination data table) for Database DDB

I'm using C# for bulk copying from SDT to DDT..

My code is something like this:

```
sqlcommand = "Delete * from DDT where locID = @LocIDParam" // @LocIDParam is the parameter for a specific location // 
then bulk copy "Select * from SDT where locID = @LocIDParam" // the steps are well known..
```

I just don't want to go for useless details..

However, my SDT has a huge data so that it causes high traffic for bulk copying the whole table

Is there anyway for bulk copying the only updated records from SDT to DDT as well as inserting the new ones???

Do you think using an SQL trigger for updated and newly inserted data is the best idea for this kind of scenarios? (trigger to insert the primary key value into a single column table for the new and update then deleting and inserting from/to DDT based on this )

PS. I don't want to use SQL replication for that since it has a lot of problems..

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to reformat this question so it is readable, instead of a wall of text.  Remove the bold text, structure your paragraphs, and highlight your code samples.

Comment: what do you mean by, "I just don't want to go for useless details..."?

Comment: Sorry..I mean the c# code for bulk copying is not an issue here..

Answer (score 0):

From the date I suppose you already fond your solution. In case not, here is how we deal with a somehow similar situation.

On the source table we have a column that shows if the data has to be send to the destination. We use a boolean but you can also have a datetime field that shows last update date.

Then our pull process does following :

1. Pull all the flagged data in a temporary table on the destination server
2. Update records that exists in both table
3. Insert all records from temporary table that don't exist in destination table
4. Drop the temporary table

If you use SQL 2008, there is a merge option that I don't know. Here a link that explains it :
[SQL 208 MERGE command](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3739131/UPSERT-Functionality-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm)

Hope this will help you if you still need.